# Java StringBuffer with Escape Char

Tags: java, stringbuffer

I have the following code shown below.   StringBuffer sbA and sbB are reading the same information.  sbA is reading it from a file (single line) , while for sbB it is hard coded in the program.   When I print them, it seems to keep the escape char is one case while not for the other.

In my case, I would like to read the information from a file but ignore the escape char as in sbB output.  I am not sure why the outputs are different.  Any suggestions.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class StringReplace {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        StringBuffer sbA = new StringBuffer();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.txt"))) {
            for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {

                if (line.isEmpty() || line.trim().equals("") || line.trim().equals("\n"))
                continue;
                sbA.append(line);
            }
            br.close();
        }

        System.out.println("sbA:  " + sbA);

        StringBuffer sbB = new StringBuffer();

        sbB.append("{\"msgData\": \"{ \"myName\": \"TheJumper\", \"myNumber\": \"35\", \"myString\": [ \"abc\", \"efg\", \"xyz\" ] }\"}");

        System.out.println("sbB:  " + sbB);

    }

}
```

The outputs are shown below:

```
sbA:  {\"msgData\": \"{ \"myName\": \"TheJumper\", \"myNumber\": \"35\", \"myString\": [ \"abc\", \"efg\", \"xyz\" ] }\"}
sbB:  {"msgData": "{ "myName": "TheJumper", "myNumber": "35", "myString": [ "abc", "efg", "xyz" ] }"}
```

Screenshot of data.txt

[image]

Comment: Your file simply has different content. As an aside, hand-crafting JSON strings is not a very good idea.

Comment: Input file data.txt has a leading escape chars already. Also do `if (line.isEmpty() || line.trim().isEmpty() || ...)` because that method is a shortcut to length()==0 unlike equals() does every kind of magic. Java 1.5+ could use StringBuilder which does not use an implicit synchronized locking methods.

Comment: Use a JSON library like [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) or [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML).

Comment: just added the screenshot of data.txt.   The above is just an example.  I am using gson.

Comment: When you write string literals in code, you need to write them in a special syntax so that you can include a `"` in them. Strings in code are not taken verbatim. Strings in text files are. There is also no meaning to `"` in a textfile. So nothing needs to take care of java syntax.

Comment: Thanks @zapl.   So, that means, we would have to use string.replace methods after reading in, before deserializing using gson.  Gson had issues with the escape char.   I am using the following command    --- GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(jsonInput, RootObject.class);

Comment: It would make more sense to fix the code that outputs the invalid JSON instead.

Comment: Thanks @Elliott.   I am using GSON.   Please see my reply to zapl.  I had problems with GSON deserialising with escape chars for the above example.

Comment: Thanks.  @Whome.   Did incorporate your line.trim().isEmpty() advise.

Comment: Thanks @biziclop.   Fixed in the problem during the creation of (legal) json.

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer as it was replaced by StringBuilder more than ten years ago.

Answer (score 0):

you can use replaceAll method to get rid of that.

```
Str.replaceAll("\\","" );
```

Comment: Thanks,   I was trying to avoid string.replace methods if I could.

Comment: No.  It gave a java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException error.  In the example case - the combination of - \" -has to be replaced with just- " -.

Comment: The following two commands worked for me.  @Kumaresan.  //myString = myString.replaceAll("\\\\\"","\"" );    //myString = myString.replace("\\\"","\"" );